# Xamarin Forms Android Accessibility for the StackLayout child ContentView label text not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

#### Description

We have created a custom Layout to add the ContentView Label when select the view label text not accessible.

[XAML]

```
    <local:CustomView AutomationId="CustomLayout" VerticalOptions="Center"  HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="300" BackgroundColor="Aqua" >
        <ContentView BackgroundColor="Yellow" HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="300">
            <Label Text="LabelText" FontSize="25" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        </ContentView>
    </local:CustomView>
```

[C#]

```
    public class CustomView : StackLayout
    {
        public CustomView()
        {
            this.SetValue(AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTreeProperty, true);

            AutomationProperties.SetName(this, this.AutomationId + "LayoutItem 1 of 1");
        }
}
```

If enable IsInAccessibleTreeProperty for both the CustomView and ContentView. The voice over will be only Label text.

#### Expected Behavior

While select the view the voice over should be LabelText + LayoutItem 1 of 1.

#### Actual Behavior

The child view text not accessible.

#### Basic Information

XF version 4.8

#### Environment

Visual Studio 2019

#### Screenshots

[image]

#### Sample LInk

[Accessibilitydemo.zip](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/files/6002593/Accessibilitydemo.zip)

Comment: Have you try to create bindable properties for your `CustomView` and set data inside the view by Bindings ? [Xamarin.Forms Bindable Properties docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties#:~:text=Examples%20of%20Xamarin.Forms%20bindable%20properties%20include%20Label.Text,%20Button.BorderRadius,,that%20is%20the%20identifier%20of%20the%20bindable%20property.)

Comment: "when select the view label text not accessible" --> this issue will be solved by adding AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree="true" to the label. You can refer this xamarin document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/accessibility/automation-properties